# How can I fine-tune my subscription to the weekly community digest?

Tags: feature-request

Because I enabled the feature at ["Edit profile and settings > Email Settings > Community digests"](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/email/digests/617), I receive a weekly email called "Veganism & Vegetarianism Stack Exchange Newsletter".

I love the idea, but I'd rather not keep receiving this same weekly email linking to the same questions (which is what has been happening, so I'm about to unsubscribe).

I'd prefer to only receive an email once any questions have become popular that I have not already seen or had only seen before they'd become active and popular.

Is this possible, or could this be added as a feature request?

Comment: I unsubscribed. I really wish there were fine-tuning available. I was tired of seeing the same links every week. Probably StackExchange at a global level should offer a better email subscription feature (not just https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com).